# How to get a code coverage report with react-create-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

If I run

```
npm test --coverage
```

the tests pass, but the coverage is not run.

When I change `package.json` to have

```
react-scripts test --coverage
```

Then, when I do `npm test` and `a` it runs the tests but not the coverage

The tests run along with the coverage report but the coverage shows all zeroes for coverage

```
 PASS  src/components/Header/SubHeader.test.js
  The <SubHeader /> component
    ✓ should render (4ms)
    ✓ should render with a goback button (1ms)
    ✓ should render

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   3 passed, 3 total
Time:        1.077s
Ran all test suites.
```

Finally, I realized that I can do

```
npm run test .
```

Question: Why don't the other methods work?

Comment: Which version of CRA and Jest are you using? I've had an issue in the past and using `npm run test -- --coverage --watchAll=false` did the trick for me (not optimal but...)

Comment: Note your first problem is explicitly called out [in the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#coverage-reporting) - you're missing `--`, so `--coverage` goes to `npm run` not `react-scripts test`. That's not related to CRA/Jest, it's just how NPM scripts work. The second seems to be a bug: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7838.

Comment: Hey Michael, i edite my answer and figured out what was the deal. Please take a look. I guess there is more to explain why --coverage is not passed with npm, but `.` is passed

Comment: Hey Michael, finally i got the answer to your question. I asked SO community myselft about `.` being passed and it regards the option and positional parameter. Take a look at my answer, i edited it

Comment: I'm sure this solution will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76001983/5650332

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After revisiting this question i figured out that if you run this you will trigger coverage command and get all results.

**SOLUTION 1**

```
npm run test -- --coverage .
```

When you are passing arguments to `npm` script, you need to add `--` before adding arguments like `--coverage`. This is just how `npm` works. [See this answer for passing arguments to npm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404223/3955557)

**SOLUTION 2**

```
yarn test --coverage .
```

**EDIT:**

I asked a question regarding `.` being passed down the command and answer is pretty much simple. `.` is passed because it is a positional parameter, in contrast to `--coverage` that is option for `npm test` command: [Why is . passed as argument to npm without -- delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087989/why-is-passed-as-argument-to-npm-without-delimiter)

**---- Problem analysis ----**

**PROBLEM 1**

`npm test --coverage` you are not passing `--coverage` argument to `test` script.

In the other case when you edit script to be:

`react-scripts test --coverage` and run `npm test` here you actually add argument `--coverage`, but in script itself, not from `npm` command

**PROBLEM 2**

When you do `npm run test .` you are passing `.` that means you want to include all files in this command.

For some reason `.` is passed to the `npm run test` script but not `--coverage`.

On the other side `yarn` passes all arguments without `--`.

Comment: Additional -- was the trick for npm to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

```
npm run test -- --coverage --watchAll
```