# Github actions , doesn't generate test report in runner but generates in local machine

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I have a react application that has jest integrated for the testing purpose.

If i run,

```
yarn web:ui:test
```

Test report as such is generated in local machine.

```
**test suites:** 1 Failed, 1 Total
**Tests:** 1 Failed, 13 passed ,14 total
**Snapshot:** 0Total
**Time**: 14.753 sec
```

but if i integrated this same step into a ci for the github/workflows in a yml file.

```
name: Run UI Tests with Enhanced Reporting
on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]  # Adjust branch(es) as needed
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  # Adjust runner OS as needed
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3  # Checkout the repository code
      - name: Use Node.js with yarn
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 19.9.0  # Adjust Node.js version as needed

      - name: get yarn cache dir path
        id: yarn-cache-dir-path
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
        
      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: yarn-cache
         # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

      - name: Install project dependencies
        # if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'false'
        run: yarn --prefer-offline #yarn install
          

      - name: Run UI tests
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          cd ./packages
          yarn web:test:ui > test-results.txt  # Capture test output

      - name: Upload test results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: test-results.txt
          path: test-results.txt

      - name: Store exit code
        id: store-exit-code
        continue-on-error: true
        run: echo "::set-output name=exit-code::$(yarn web:test:ui)"
        
      - name: Check test results
        if: steps.store-exit-code.outputs.exit-code != 0
        run: echo "Test suite failed with exit code ${{ steps.store-exit-code.outputs.exit-code }}"
```

the report generated is only of txt version that is too long to read.
[not so useful Txt file Generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/autqM.png)

Question: Why is the report coverage not generated like in the local machine?

the blogs i have referred to are:
[first](https://qa-nora.medium.com/unit-testing-with-jest-and-integration-with-github-actions-bc241b31d257)
[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696265/how-to-get-a-code-coverage-report-with-react-create-app)

**Both have been tested yet still i am only seeing the long list of error without the proper reporting.**
[old-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165756/unable-to-obtain-test-report-in-ci-testing-despite-being-generated-in-the-local)

i tried implementing the --coverage flag in the jest line of package json as referred in the stackoverflow question ([How to get a code coverage report with react-create-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696265/how-to-get-a-code-coverage-report-with-react-create-app))
and other marketplace actions just to obtain the report . i also have linked other blogs i have refereed.

Comment: "i am only seeing the long list of error without the proper reporting.". This is kind of the important part that you left out.

Comment: I had included the image of the txt file generated if that what you are looking for. I also have edited so that user wouldn't overlook the given image.